# Efficient element-wise function computation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following optimization problem:

> Given two np.arrays `X`,`Y` and a function `K` I would like to compute as fast as possible the matrix incidence gram_matrix where the `(i,j)-th` element is computed as `K(X[i],Y[j])`.

Here is an implementation using nested for-loops, which are acknowledged to be the slowest to solve these kind of problems.

```
def proxy_kernel(X,Y,K):
    gram_matrix = np.zeros((X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]))
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
        for j, y in enumerate(Y):
            gram_matrix[i, j] = K(x, y)
    return gram_matrix
```

Comment: Do we know anything else about the function `K`?

Comment: The function K is supposed to be a generic kernel function. For example one of these http://crsouza.com/2010/03/kernel-functions-for-machine-learning-applications/#rational

Comment: What is `X.ndim`, `Y.ndim`?  What kinds of inputs does `K` take?  Scalar, 1d vectors, something higher?

Comment: Some of the same kernels have been implemented in `scikit-learn`: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the nested loops using [`numpy.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to build a table of entries in `x` and `y`, and [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to apply a function to all entries in the table:

```
def tabulate(x, y, f):
    """Return a table of f(x, y)."""
    return np.vectorize(f)(*np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True))
```

For example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> tabulate(np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(1, 4), operator.mul)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

This is about twice as fast as `proxy_kernel`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> X = Y = np.arange(2000)
>>> timeit(lambda:proxy_kernel(X, Y, operator.mul), number=1)
2.174600816098973
>>> timeit(lambda:tabulate(X, Y, operator.mul), number=1)
0.9889162541367114
```

but it still has to evaluate the slow Python code in `f` for each entry in the table. To really speed things up you need to use whole-array operations throughout. Depending on how you've written `f`, it may be possible to do this directly. For example, if you have something like:

```
def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(-0.5 * np.abs(x - y))
```

then this is already suitable for applying to whole arrays:

```
>>> f(*np.meshgrid(np.arange(4), np.arange(4), sparse=True))
array([[ 1.        ,  0.60653066,  0.36787944,  0.22313016],
       [ 0.60653066,  1.        ,  0.60653066,  0.36787944],
       [ 0.36787944,  0.60653066,  1.        ,  0.60653066],
       [ 0.22313016,  0.36787944,  0.60653066,  1.        ]])
```

and this is about five times as fast as using [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
>>> timeit(lambda:f(*np.meshgrid(X, Y, sparse=True)), number=1)
0.1973482659086585
```

Comment: This is similar to the answer I gave this poster (different name) on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30088791/901925.  `vectorize` can double the speed, but real speedup requires getting at the internals of `K`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Python, you will almost always be faster if you can make use of code implemented in C.

For instance, you might be able to convert X (Y) into a matrix where the row (column) is repeated multiple times to fit the size of your output matrix.  Then you can maybe find a C-implemented function somewhere that combines matrices element-wise with a user-provided kernel, and that might save a little time for looping.

Just found in the docs this:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/numpy-ref-1.9.1.pdf#section*.1764
This seems to be doing the repeating already(?).

But in any case, your solution seems pretty good already.  You might be able to squeeze a bit for the "looping over matrices" part, and for the cost of assignment to particular positions in the matrices (including Python function call overhead), but the kernel K, which I assume outweighs that cost by far, will still need to be called the same amount of times. :)